# JwtReadError (401 Status) when attempting to OAuth Authentication Flow a second time

Tags: oauth, banno-digital-toolkit

I am in the process of building a plugin for Banno Mobile & Online.  While following the [documentation](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/authentication-framework/) provided by the Jack Henry Digital Toolkit for authentication using the OAuth architecture, I was able to successfully complete the authentication flow and receive an access token and user profile information.

After some period of time has elapsed (in my testing, it appeared to be around 10 minutes), if I attempt to initiate the OAuth flow again, I receive an HTTP status code 401 response from the initial redirect to the /a/consumer/api/v0/oidc URL.  I will continue to get the 401 response using the OAuth flow until I manually navigate to the Banno Online site and login manually.

For my purpose, the use case would be a user that goes idle while in the full screen view of the plugin.  I would like to re-authenticate the user, but attempting to do so by initiating the OAuth flow causes the above failure if a certain amount of time has elapsed.  If I attempt to initiate the OAuth flow inside of 10 minutes from the initial authentication, it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

An `Access Token` currently has a lifetime of 10 minutes from when that specific token was issued, which sounds like what you're seeing. See [Access Tokens](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/authentication-framework/overview/tokens/) for reference.

One way of handling the expiration of an Access Token is to request a `Refresh Token` during the initial authentication flow. A Refresh Token can be exchanged for a new Access Token. See [Refresh Tokens](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/authentication-framework/overview/tokens/) and [OpenID Connect and OAuth 2.0](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/authentication-framework/overview/openidconnectoauth/) for reference.

In this case, you can request a Refresh Token during the initial authentication flow by including the OAuth scope `https://api.banno.com/consumer/auth/offline_access` in the authentication request.

The Refresh Token can be exchanged for a new Access Token using the `POST ​/oidc​/token` endpoint. See the [API Reference](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/consumer-api/api-reference/v0/oauth-and-openid-connect/details/) for details.

Comment: Does exchanging the refresh token for a new access token re-authenticate the user? If the user is in my application for longer than 10 minutes and then gets transferred back to their online banking, would they be asked to authenticate again after i asked for another access token?

Comment: No, it does not re-authenticate the user. The user would have to re-authenticate into digital banking. This is covered in the 'you must manage your own session' part of this guide: https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/guides/designinganddevelopingplugins/#authentication

Comment: Consider, for example, a [data aggregator](https://banno.com/data-aggregators/). After connecting an app, the user doesn't necessarily have to return to digital banking (and frequently does not). The data aggregator can use Refresh Tokens and exchange them for a new Access Token in a cycle (e.g., daily) to get the user's latest data and make updates (e.g., budgets in a personal financial management app). The user wouldn't be re-authenticated in digital banking in that use case either (which they wouldn't want to be as they don't have to be online for the PFM magic to happen).

Comment: I do manage my own session. However, the member goes into my app and fills out a form that can take longer than 10 minutes. After the form is done, I would have a button that when clicked takes the member back to their online banking account. Is this not possible then?

Comment: You could add a button, for sure e.g. in the case of the _Garden_ demo institution you could do something like this: [Return to Digital Banking](https://digital.garden-fi.com/). The user won't _stay_ logged in beyond the session length, though so they would have to log in again if their session has timed out.